# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types when adding values to array

Tags: php, arrays

I get an error when trying to rebuild an array with below code:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types

```
$id = '9242';
$supergroup = array('9242' => 1, '9243' => 0, '9244' => 2, '9245' => 0);
$supergroupnew = [];

array_walk_recursive($supergroup, function($item, $key) use(&$id) {
    if ($key == $id) {
        $supergroupnew += [ $key => $item ];
    } else {
        $supergroupnew += [ $key => "0" ];
    }
});

echo "<h1>Original Array:</h1>";
print_r($supergroup);   

echo "<h1>New Array:</h1>";
print_r($supergroupnew);
```

Other answers suggest that I am trying to do some arithmetic on an array however I cannot see this in the above code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: I can't see that error within the list?

Comment: Oh hey, it should be added then. Anyway, you can't add values to an array with `+` in PHP. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `$supergroupnew` is not defined inside the function and the actual error would read:

> Notice: Undefined variable: supergroupnew

You need to make the following small change:

```
array_walk_recursive($supergroup, function($item, $key) use($id, &$supergroupnew) {
// removed & from id
// added &$supergroupnew to use statement, you can access/modify this external variable
```

Having said that, using `+=` on arrays will create a *union* instead of appending. [Quote](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand
>   array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the
>   left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the
>   right-hand array will be ignored.

You should use `[]` instead unless there is something I don't understand.

Comment: Thanks so much i think i was looking at that for far too long

Comment: Not sure what using [] should look like can you expand that? This works perfectly however now with += im just trying to duplicate that original array however only give 0 for the $item if $id does not match the $key in array.

Comment: In your code, `$supergroupnew += [ $key => $item ];` will insert the key `$key` with value `$item` into `$supergroupnew`. However if `$key` already exists in `$supergroupnew` its value will not be changed. To me it is a code smell although this will not cause any problem in your code. I would rather use `array_walk` instead of `array_walk_recursive` and use `$supergroupnew[$key] = $item`.

Comment: Ok the ids are always unique and supergroupnew will always start empty so I think the code will be fine in this case? I will update to your way for best practice in future as I get what you mean I will have a bit of a read on array_walk as not quite sure on the differences there.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - Apparently you can add arrays to arrays with `+` so disregard this answer.

You can't add values to an array with `+` in PHP. Try it like this:

```
$supergroupnew = [];

array_walk_recursive($supergroup, function($item, $key) use(&$id) {
    if ($key == $id) {
        $supergroupnew[] = [ $key => $item ];
    } else {
        $supergroupnew[] = [ $key => "0" ];
    }
});
```

Comment: Please check the other answer, you can use `+` and `$supergroupnew` will be forgotten once the function finishes.

Comment: Yep indeed. Didn't know you could append arrays with arrays with `+`. Learn something every day :)

Comment: Think you have to be very careful with `+` as it's not the same as `[]`.  So depends on what your trying to do will affect the way you do it.

Comment: I was just reading the http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php manual and copied mrgreens example for the loop not sure what to go for just want the array in same order to original with some slight modifications.

Comment: When i use equal like you suggest the array is just the last processed value overiding everything previous. += seems to work perfectly fine however.

Comment: Note the two square brackets before the equal! But as said, yes, `+=` works fine for adding arrays to arrays.